# What is the most appropriate noun for 'a person who is ostracized'?

Tags: vocabulary

Is there any variation/conjugation of the word 'ostracism' that refers to a person who is ostracized?

Similar to 'conviction' and 'a convict'.

The word ostracism is used by the author I am citing and I would preferably use his own choice of words, but I'm not sure it will be possible for this construction.

Comment: The Biblical [Jeremiah was an outcast](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22Jeremiah+was+an+outcast%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), and I've always understood the 1972 western [Jeremiah Johnson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeremiah_Johnson_(film)) starring Robert Redford to be an allusion to that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It’s unrelated to *ostracise*, but how about *outcast?*

*Ostracism* comes from Greek *ostrakon* (related to *osteon*, “bone”), which referred to the clay ballots on which individuals would write the names of those they wished to banish from their community. *Outcast* is much more literal, and a much older word in English.

Answer (score 11):

A person who is ostracized is a *pariah*:

> **pariah**
>   *noun*
>   1 an outcast: *they were treated as social pariahs*.

[source: NOAD]

Comment: pariah sounds like it has negative or accusatory connotation, but I'm not sure (non native speaker). The author refers to himself as being ostracized, which is different than viewing oneself as a pariah, no? Outcast is maybe more neutral?

Comment: @joon: I agree. *Pariah* is a much more negative term. It originally referred to a member of a low Indian caste, and was only recently (1819) extended to mean “social outcast”.

Comment: So who said it couldn't be negative?

Answer (score 3):

A third, somewhat legalistic possibility is *persona non grata*.

Answer (score -1):

"expatriate"; exile, removed, expelled

Comment: This answer would be better with correct formatting for a definition, and perhaps a link. See Robustos answer for an example.